# Why map method does not return array of object?

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

```
let x = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
let result = Object.keys(x).map((i) => {
  console.log(i) ;
  return ({i :x[i]});
})
```

why result is

```
[{i: 1},{i: 2},{i: 3}]
```

? In console, value of i i.e a,b,c is being printed. What happens during return?

Comment: what is `x` in your code ?

Comment: The code above **does** return an array of objects. What makes you think it doesn't? Also, what's `x`?

Comment: If you want to use `value` of your variable as a property of object you should use square brackets `[i]`

Comment: Your question was answered

Answer (score 3):

> Why map method does not return array of object?

It does.

> What happens during return?

The `return ({i :x[i]});` line means:

- Create an object.
- Give it a property called `"i"` (not the **value** of `i`, the actual literal name `"i"`) with the value from `x[i]`.
- Return that as the value for this map iteration, which will be used in the result array.

The result is an array of objects, each with one property called `"i"`.

If you meant to use the *value* of `i`, you'd need to use a computed property name. There's also no reason for the `()` around the object literal:

```
return {[i]: x[i]};
//      ^^^------------- computed property name
```

Live Example:

```js
let x = {a:1,b:2,c:3};
let result = Object.keys(x).map((i) => {
  console.log(i) ;
  return {[i]: x[i]};
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This was introduced in ES2015. In ES5 and earlier, you'd have to create the object first, then add the property to it afterward.